# Log4net AdoNetAppender not saving to Db

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm having trouble with my AdoNetAppender- it's just not logging. I've gone through the log4net manual and various other links but can't see what I'm doing wrong. The following is my config file and how I'm calling it so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="***" />
  <commandText value="dbo.spx_CreatePageLog" />
  <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
  <!--<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>-->
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@HTTPMethod" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="10" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@URI" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="512" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%URI{URI}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@RequestData" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="1024" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%RequestData{RequestData}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@UserID" />
    <dbType value="int" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%UserID{UserID}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@UserToDealerID" />
    <dbType value="int" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%UserToDealerID{UserToDealerID}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@AdminID" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="256" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%AdminID{AdminID}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@SessionID" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="256" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%SessionID{SessionID}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@BrowserInfo" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="1024" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%BrowserInfo{BrowserInfo}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <!--<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>-->
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</root>
```

```
string RequestData = auditModel.ParameterValues.GetDictionaryIntoString<string>();
        string BrowserInfo = auditModel.BrowserInfo.GetDictionaryIntoString<string>();

        //log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["HTTPMethod"] = auditModel.Method;
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["URI"] = auditModel.RequestUrl;
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["RequestData"] = RequestData;
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["UserID"] = auditModel.UserID;
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["UserToDealerID"] = auditModel.UserToDealerID;
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["AdminID"] = auditModel.AdminID;
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["SessionID"] = "123456"; //auditModel.SessionID;
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["BrowserInfo"] = BrowserInfo;

        Logger.Debug(auditModel.Method);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use stored Procedures to store Log4Net log in your database. 
From what you have, I can only think of these two things that might be causing the problem.

1) The value of conversionPattern is not correct. See below:

```
   <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@HTTPMethod" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="10" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@URI" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="512" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{URI}" /> <- here use property instead of "UserID"
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@RequestData" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="1024" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{RequestData}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@UserID" />
    <dbType value="int" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{UserID}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@UserToDealerID" />
    <dbType value="int" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{UserToDealerID}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@AdminID" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="256" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{AdminID}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@SessionID" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="256" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{SessionID}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@BrowserInfo" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="1024" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{BrowserInfo}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
```

2) If you change to above code, and it still doesn't work. Consider if the log4Net parameters are
 matching the parameters in your stored Procedures. You can try to use fake data and execute 
 stored procedures anywhere like before Logger.Debug(). If it works, the problem is,

```
 Logger.Debug(auditModel.Method);
```

For more information you can read this articles:

http://www.l4ndash.com/News/tabid/69/ctl/ArticleView/mid/413/articleId/5/Using-Log4Net-to-log-from-Database-Stored-procedures.aspx

http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2006/02/log4net-versus-enterprise-library-2-0-logging-application-block-part-ii-database-logging/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where would I put that?